# Cycle page URLs by appending json value to URL and refresh on interval

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to get my cms site to append page IDs to my static URL and cycle through them, using javascript or possibly ajax.

The url now if you click on Display 3 is `http://local.CMSTest.com/showDisplay.php?display=3`
which is what I expect coming from the link on the previous page.

I'm trying to change the array i've been using to strictly use a json and I want to use javascript in order to set the url and after an interval of time, refresh the page to the next url.

Below is the json print for each returned result of my current array, which is two pages.

So in this case, on page load I want to 
1. Append the first object's pageID to the URL which would look like `http://local.CMSTest.com/showDisplay.php?display=3&pageID=104`
2. Use the other elements of the first JSON object (panel_type_id, content, etc.) to fill out the html
3. Use the duration (in seconds) of the json in order to set the interval
4. When that time is up, refresh the page, now appending the next pageID `http://local.CMSTest.com/showDisplay.php?display=3&pageID=116` and so on, in a loop.

The current javascript prints what I expect to be the next URL in the console, but I'm expecting it to be appending the pageID of the first array/json result to the current active URL and it's not, it's just showing the `?diplay=3`. So I feel like it's on the right track but I'm missing something somewhere

Here's the JSON structure:

```
{pageID: "104", page_type_id: "1", display_id: "3", slide_order: null, duration: "54", …}
active:"1"
background_img:"images/BG_spring.svg"
contID:"165"
cont_id:"165"
content:"<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵<head>↵</head>↵<body>↵<p>This is the first page</p>↵</body>↵</html>"
display_id:"3"
duration:"54"
pageID:"104"
page_id:"104"
page_type_id:"1"
panel_id:"114"
panel_type_id:"1"

{pageID: "116", page_type_id: "1", display_id: "3", slide_order: null, duration: "54", …}
active:"1"
background_img:"images/BG_spring.svg"
contID:"166"
cont_id:"166"
content:"<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵<head>↵</head>↵<body>↵<p>This is the second page</p>↵</body>↵</html>"
display_id:"3"
duration:"54"
pageID:"116"
page_id:"116"
page_type_id:"1"
panel_id:"113"
panel_type_id:"1"
```

The current HTML

```
<?php foreach($showDisplayResult as $showDisplays): ?>
    <?php if($showDisplays['page_type_id'] == 1){ ?>

        <?php //print_r($showDisplays);?>
        <div class="row top">
            <?php include 'banner.php'?>
        </div>

        <div class="row middle" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $showDisplays['background_img']?>);">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <?if($showDisplays['panel_type_id'] == 1){?>
                <div class="fullContent" style="/*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);*/ height: 100%; ">
                <?php echo $showDisplays['content']?>
                </div>
                <?}?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row bottom">
            <?php include 'ticker.php';?>
        </div>

    <?php }?> 
<?php endforeach?>
```

And javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setDisplay() {
  let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
  let pageID = params.get("pageID");
  let disply = params.get("display");
  // set the html based on pageID and display
}

function getNextURL() {
  // encode your php array to json
  let obj = <?php echo json_encode($showDisplays); ?>;

  let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
  params.set("pageID", obj.pageID);
  params.set("display", obj.display_id);

  let url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
  let nextURL = url + "?" + params.toString();
  console.log(nextURL);
  console.log(obj);
  return nextURL
}

getNextURL();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's logging out the correct value, which it looks like it should be, then all you are missing is changing the actual URL of your window:

```
window.location.href = getNextUrl();
```

Keep in mind that you haven't implemented your delay yet so this would currently keep refreshing to the next page without any delay.

**Update to answer comment question:**

To be able to update the url only after the obj.duration, you could do the following for your `getNextURL` function:

```
// encode your php array to json
let obj = <?php echo json_encode($showDisplays); ?>;

let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
params.set("pageID", obj.pageID);
params.set("display", obj.display_id);

let url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
let nextURL = url + "?" + params.toString();
window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = nextURL;
}, obj.duration * 1000);
```

In the above code, I have assumed that your durations are in seconds however window.setTimeout works with milliseconds thus the `* 1000`.

What this will do is after it creates the next URL, it will wait for `obj.duration` number of seconds before assigning the next URL to be the current url.

Comment: So 2 questions: where would I need to set that line? And then would I set the delay in its own function?

Comment: @TomN. Updated my answer to answer your question

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm about to experiment with this now

Comment: Ok this works in terms of the refresh and after refresh it shows the url as ```/showDisplay.php?display=3&pageID=116``` which is what I want. But the only issue is the initial page load just still shows ```?display=3``` where it should have ```?display=3&pageID=104```. I wonder if it's because I'm using a foreach for my array? It only seems to get the last element of the array in JSON. if I do console.log(obj) it only shows the last element, pageID116 as well

Comment: @simon_K do you have a moment to chat on this? It mostly works except for initial page load

Comment: You left our chat but did you have any ideas on how I should alter this given what I told you?

Comment: @simon_k did you have any feedback on this from our chat?